# Parse a string representation of an array of arrays, into 2 separate arrays of arrays that are numbers

Tags: javascript

I can think of how to do this but it would get extremely complicated. So I have to turn this:

```
[[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]], [[1,0],[1,1]]]
```

into 2 arrays:

The first would be: `[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2]]` - An array of arrays of numbers

The second would be: `[[1,0], [1,1]]` - Another array of arrays of numbers

How can I do this simply and efficiently without doing a whole bunch of string methods and checking?

Comment: Why not just parse it as JSON with `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Didn't know about that

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
let x = "[[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]], [[1,0],[1,1]]]"
y = JSON.parse(x)
```

and `y` would be array of arrays.